# How to sort sql by other sql table?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, wordpress

I have two tables.

```
wp_term_relationships
     term_taxonomy_id
     ...

wp_posts
     ID
     ...
     menu_order
```

What i am doing is taking all values from wp_term_relationships

```
$results = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT `object_id` 
                               FROM `wp_term_relationships` 
                               WHERE `term_taxonomy_id`='".$cat_id."'");
```

and then taking for each values that I need

```
foreach($results as $result){

   $postarrayStringINT[] = $result->object_id;

    $results2 = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM `wp_posts` 
                                    WHERE `ID`='".$result->object_id."' ");
```

But I need them to be in correct order, and that is menu_order table in wp_posts, how to do so?

I tried something like that :

```
"SELECT `object_id` FROM `wp_term_relationships` 
 WHERE `term_taxonomy_id`='".$cat_id."' JOIN (SELECT * FROM 'wp_posts') 
 ORDER BY 'menu_order'"
```

How to do so ? How to take one value from table and sort/**order by** it by other tables values ?

Comment: what are the columns of your tables ? usually you have to join both tables to be able to sort

Comment: wp_term_relationships - object_id ,term_taxonomy_id,term_order ;;;                 wp_posts - ID, menu_order (as i wrote in the top, there are many other columns in wp_posts by they dont make difference)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should try something like that:

```
SELECT field1, field2, field3, etc... 
FROM wp_posts
INNER JOIN wp_term_relationships on wp_posts.id = wp_term.object_id
WHERE term_taxonomy_id=".$cat_id."
ORDER BY menu_order
```

Comment: IT WORKED !! THanks. I jsut changed  wp_term.object_id to wp_term_relationships.object_id and it worked perfectly :) thanks